# Master Source Code Base and Various Releases/Customers

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, azure-devops

This is sort of a theoretical question, but also something I would like to implement.

I have a project, and this project is essentially the main source code and any new features will be added to this project and would be copied to the "children" of this project. So if Customer A comes along, we copy the main source with the latest features. Then if Customer B wants to use the system we take the latest version of the main source (which may have had other new features built into it). So we would be building off the main source each time.

That said, I would like to be able to merge features into other customer versions as well so they could have the latest features, if requested. Not really sure a good approach or tools to help with this. Would branching solve this issue?

This is an ASP.Net MVC Web System using an old version of TFS (2010) but using the latest version of Visual Studio (2019)

Example:

```
Main Code
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                  |                                |
       |Customer A        |                                |
                          |New Feature Added to Main Code  |
                                                           |Customer B
```

So in this example Customer A joins, we take a copy of the code base. Then some new features are added and then Customer B gets the latest code base that include the latest and greatest.

Customer A finds out about the awesome new features and wants access to those. This is where the strategy starts to get blurry... how would a developer get the latest features into the code base without copying and pasting various files?

Comment: This is a matter of branching. What branching model are you using?

Comment: Currently nothing really, I took over this system recently and nothing was really being used as far as branching previousy.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote, sorry I could not find something to describe what I need on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well normally git would be better for a sophisticated branching strategy...

But,... i think for your case it makes more sense to version your software properly, e.g. [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org), and make the versions (releases) available for your customers. They can decide for themselves if they want to buy a newer version or buy an upgrade version or get a free upgrade for bugfixes... etc...

anyway, start with a simple model and adopt when customer demands/requirements getting clearer

Comment: That makes sense. So for instance when a customer decides to upgrade... would I just pull the main trunk into their branch and then make sure it works/compiles/is bug free? Then check into their branch for publishing?

Sorry if I sound dumb, I am used to just checking into a main trunk and moving forward. I want to do this different.

Comment: not exactly. First, i would not recommend having 1 branch per customer, in case you want to hotfix from main branch you will end up merging the hotfix to every customer branch. imagine you have 200 customers... create a branching model to support your versions and then decide how long will you support (keep the branch) for a version. i.e.:at one point, make a branch, e.g. ver 5.4, create a release for this branch, and decide for example if you keep and support this version until you reach version for example 5.8.. and so on.When a customers decides to upgrade, he just downloads the new release